# Xamarin UILabel not updating

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios

I've a basic for loop that's basically download files. It's supposed to update the label as long as it progress.

By searching here at Stack Overflow, I found an orientation to use SetNeedsDisplay(). But it's still refuses to update. Any idea ?

```
for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
                    status.Text = "Downloading file " + (i + 1) + " of " + files.Length + "...";
                    status.SetNeedsDisplay();
                    string remoteFile = assetServer + files[i];
                    var webClient2 = new WebClient();
                    string localFile = files[i];
                    string localPath3 = Path.Combine(documentsPath, localFile);
                    webClient2.DownloadFile(remoteFile, localPath3);
    }
```

Comment: Are you running this on a background thread?

Comment: Nope.Nope.Nope.

Comment: Do not block the UI thread, perform the download on a background thread, something as simple as `await Task.Run(...)`, and update the `UILabel` on the UI thread.

Answer (score 1):

As previously suggested try to avoid blocking the UI when doing heavy transactions in it. WebClient already has a async method which you can use.

```
webClient2.DownloadFileasync(new System.Uri(remoteFile), localPath3);
```

and to prevent you from accessing the UI from a different thread use the built-in method **InvokeOnMainThread** when accessing UI elements.

```
InvokeOnMainThread (() => {
    status.Text = "Downloading file " + (i + 1) + " of " + files.Length + "...";
    status.SetNeedsDisplay ();
});
```

and finally use the **using** statement to help you with the resources disposal.

```
using (var webClient2 = new WebClient ())
{
    webClient2.DownloadFileAsync (new System.Uri (remoteFile), localPath3);
}
```

You could also have the iteration inside the using statement this way you don't have to create a WebClient object for each file instead you will use the same object to download all files available in your `files` array.